# Im struggling with identifying the capacitance on this cap

Tags: capacitance

Cant find capacitance for this capacitor marked x1 100v UD any help appreciated [image] can find capacitance for this capacitor

Comment: The biggest one i forgot to mention need to find out capacitance  marked x1 100v UD electrolytic solid cap

Answer (score 3):

it is 100uF, 35V electrolytic capacitor

x1 - lot number

100 - capacitance

v - volatge rating (an alphabet not voltage "V")

ud - is series

please follow the following image for Reading capacitor values for UD series
[image]

Comment: thanx for answer how did u get 35v volts how do i in future read these safety caps

Comment: I had edited the answer please check.

Comment: are you ok with my answer?

Comment: @Aaronc did you verify the datasheet, is the answer ok to you?

Comment: im trying to troubleshoot a dead sagem hdd recorder 12v it has power upto the board but remains dead no leds nothing any tips would really help